# ZF script from command line as cron

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, command-line-interface, bootstrapping

I am trying to figure out how to make a Zend Framework script to run as a cronjob from a command line, but the bootstrap setup below seems to fail:

```
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../') . '/');
define('APPLICATION_PATH', BASE_PATH . 'application/');
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'live');

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(
        implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
            realpath(BASE_PATH . 'library'),
            realpath('/usr/src/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library')
            ) // closes array
        ) // closes implode
        . get_include_path()
    );

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
// Load only the ressources that you need
$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap(array('db', 'mail'));
```

It fails on the `$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap(array('db', 'mail'))` line. I am puzzled. It seems to be able to access `frontController` module, but neither `db` or `mail` modules works. Any ideas what it could be?

**Edit:** Below are the error details:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "db" not found' in /usr/src/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:694
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/src/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(632): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('db')
#1 /usr/src/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(586): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(Array)
#2 /www/.../live/htdocs/v2/cron/bootstrap.php(26): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(Array)
#3 /www/.../live/htdocs/v2/cron/send-leads.php(2): require_once('/www/...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /usr/src/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php on line 694
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you just do `$application->bootstrap(array('db', 'mail'));`? And when you say 'it fails', what do you mean if there are no errors?

Comment: @TimFountain, no, no difference. I say it fails because this bootstrapping code is being included into another file, and no output past that `require_once` line follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

`$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap(array('db'))`

to

`$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap(array('multidb'))`

fixes the issue. I am not exactly sure about the `mail` resource, though, but judging by similar issues other people were having, I want to say it has something to do with what resources you have specified in your /configs/application.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this on wrong way.
In you cron script at this at the beginning of file.

```
// for testing on local host
//example: php script.php development 
if($argv[1]){
    putenv("APPLICATION_ENV=".$argv[1]);
}
else{
    putenv("APPLICATION_ENV=live");
}
define("RUN_APP",true);

//put right path here!!!!
require ( dirname( $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "/../../../../public/index.php");

//your script code goes here
```

That last require is index file in your public zend folder.
With this approach you will have access to all bootstrap options (custom model classes, mail options etc).

I have done this thousand times.

Tell me if you are having trouble  with this.

Comment: I realize that index.php in your public folder is very similar to what I am doing, but as far as I understand, one issue with this that you actually execute your default controller action by doing `$application->bootstrap()->run()`, which i don't need.